# Different result between Rapidminer and Python imblearn

Tags: python, multiclass-classification, class-imbalance, smote, imbalanced-learn

I'm currently working on imbalanced classification problem. However i found different result between SMOTE in rapidminer and SMOTE in imblearn (python). rapidminer SMOTE give 15-20% improvement on cross validation, but imblearn only give 5%. is it possible? i'm using random forest as basic learner with default config for both